# Why does part of my if statement show, but the other part does not?

Tags: python

I've been stuck on this program for a while now. Basically, I've been trying to get my code to display the answer portion of my code.

I am able to make it display the failure message, but it won't work when I get the answer right and display the congratulatory message. I've used two while loops (one may seem repetitive and unnecessary), one for loop, and three if statements. Help, please!!

I have used all of the loops i said earlier and tried deleting some. My prof told me to delete one of the loops and change my 'i = 0' which I have all tried but nothing seems to work. I understand that the 'chances' variable in unnecessary and I could replace it with 'i' but for some reason when I do, it does work as it did before. even more, issues arise then before.

```
list_of_words = ['cool', 'ok', 'sure', 'sickkkk', 'what', 'how']  
random_word = random.choice(list_of_words)        
for letter in random_word:  
    underscore = '_ '*len(random_word)  
print('The answer so far is '+underscore+' ')        

answer = random_word
answer_list = ['_']*len(answer)  
chances = 0
incorrect = 4

underscore = ''  



while chances <len(answer) and incorrect > 0:
    i = 0
    guess = input('Guess a letter ('+ str(incorrect) +' guesses remaining):')  
    while i< len(answer):
        if answer[i] == guess: 
            answer_list[i] = guess 

        i = i + 1 

    if guess in answer:  
        print('the answer so far is ' + ' '.join(answer_list))  
        chances += 1

    else:                       
        print('the answer so far is ' + ' '.join(answer_list))
        chances -= 1
        incorrect = incorrect - 1

if guess == answer_list:
    print('Good job! You found the word '+answer+'.')

else:
    print('Not quite, the correct word was '+answer+'. Better luck next time.')

input('Press enter to end the game.')
```

Comment: `guess` is a string, and `answer_list` is a list. Those two things will never be equal.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code that are making the algorithm fail. The first one is that you are comparing `answer_list` to `guess` while you should be comparing it to `answer`.

Even after fixing this, the congratulatory message is never displayed because `answer == answer_list` is never `True`. Try printing `answer` and printing `answer_list` before the line `if answer == answer_list:`, and comparing both variables yourself to see if they look equal, and you will find the second problem.

When you do, you may find the `join` function useful. Here's an example:

```
my_list = ["I", "like", "code"]
''.join(my_list)
> 'Ilikecode'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be `guess == answer_list`. `guess` is a single letter, while `answer_list` is made up of several letters. I think what you meant to write was `''.join(answer_list) == answer`.